# I cannot send GMAIL using Outlook 2016

Tags: macos, ms-office, gmail, smtp

I have Outlook 2016 and I'm trying to pickup my gmail using IMAP.  I can receive emails, but it does not send when doing a test send on setting up the email. Error code: 0x800cce05

SMTP Server:
smtp.gmail.com
My outgoing server requires authentication (ticked)
Port: 465 (SSL). Also tried 587, SSL, TLS

It works fine on my mobile, works fine with Office 2010. Works fine with Windows 10 mail. But not with Office Outlook 2016.

Comment: I have the same problem, was on a long online help chat with Microsoft today, I let them to control my computer online, they tried everything, after two hours he gave up. They will get back to me tomorrow with some level 2 highly trained manager.. lol. Will see..

Answer (score -1):

it might be that you have to allow less secure apps to connect to your gmail account: https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

more details:https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/gmail/LhWVrYZc_Eo/5EMpldFUC3wJ